# How does everyone handle "," comma within a field in csv file while importing it

Tags: apex

I am trying to import a csv file and parse the csv file. 
I have the code working fine, except where we have a "," within a field in the csv.

While reading the csv its considering the comma as the field delimiter as it should. How do data loaders handle this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Data Loader cannot handle this implicitly because there is no logical path to follow. In case your Data Loader CSV file for import will contain commas for any of the field content, you will have to enclose the contents within double quotation marks " ". Data Loader will be able to handle this.

For example,

```
Column_1__c,Column_2__c,Column_3__c
AAA,"BBB,CCC",DDD
```

If you are creating the import CSV in Excel, the quotation marks will be inserted automatically by Excel whenever a comma is detected in any cell - Saving the CSV in Excel and opening the same in Notepad reveals the enclosing quotation marks for cells containing commas.

Comment: You can actually read the spec on the CSV file format at http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#page-2 it's only a handful of points and is well worth the read.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you are needing upload & parse the CSV from a custom page, but if you are I have developed the following CSV parser that handles quote-enclosed fields containing commas:

https://gist.github.com/lukemcfarlane/dcd58a2ce703ae4171b7

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I was able to handle it, but requires stripping the "," from the field.
if (field.Contains(','))
   {
     field= field.Replace(',', ' ');
   }

Answer (score 0):

I had a hybrid issue where I didn't need the entire file wrapped in quotes, only the cells that contained sentences.  I ended up using a CONCAT formula and hard linking to a cell with " as the value on each end and the cell with the sentence in between.

For example, Cell A1 = " | Cell A2 = Here, is a comma. |
= CONCAT($A$1,A2,$A$1)
= "Here, is a comma."

This method also works with Asian, Arabic, and other special characters.

Save the file/sheet as CSV, verify the extra quotes are in place using Notepad++ or similar.